# pyqt5 py2app/pyinstaller MacOS High Sierra QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap

Tags: null, pyqt5, pyinstaller, py2app, qpixmap

I am using py2app on a pyqt5 script to develop a standalone application.
The program must show a photo in the dialog. I use the script below and it works fine on Ubuntu and windows, both when using python and also when using pyinstaller standalone executables.

On MacOS High Sierra, however, when use python to run the scripts the image shows just fine. When I make executables using either py2app or pyinstaller, I get the famous `QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap` error.

Here is the code for putting the image up:

```
pic = QLabel(Dialog)
height_label = 300
pic.resize(Dialog.width(), height_label)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "main.jpg"))
pic.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(pic.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
```

Comment: execute `print(os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "main.jpg")))`

Comment: You're absolutely right, when executing the program with double click, the os.getcwd() will default to home directory and not the program's directory.

Comment: change `os.getcwd()` to: `QtCore.QCoreApplication().applicationDirPath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program needs specific data of images, it's better to specify the files in the py2app setup.py with `DATA_FILES = ["main.jpg"].`

os.getcwd() would only redirect the executable directory if the executable is run from the commandline. Otherwise it will default to the system's home directory.
This will work just fine:

```
    file = sys.argv[0]
    dirname = os.path.dirname(file)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(
        os.path.join(dirname, "main.jpg"))
```